# INVALID_OPERATION on glTexSubImage3D()

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to use a 3D_TEXTURE as a big custom buffer, because TEXTURE_BUFFER is limited to 128MB on most GPUs, but 3D_TEXTURES don't have a limit. Unfortuantely I also can't use GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, because it is limited to the glsl data types (float, uint, int) and I need byte-wise access.

I debugged the code and found that it throws the error code 1282 => GL_INVALID_OPERATION, when I try filling the data in the texture with glTexSubImage3D(). But I can't explain the error code. I checked all cases in [the reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage3D.xhtml),
but to my knowledge none of the named reasons for GL_INVALID_OPERATION shouldn't be the case in my opinion.

```
  // main code:
  genSuperTex(1024);
  fillSuperTex();
```

---

```
void genSuperTex(int inputSize) {
  superBufferSize = inputSize; // saving the z size of the buffer...

  GLuint gerror;
  glGenTextures(1, &superBufferID);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, superBufferID);
  gerror = glGetError();
  if (gerror) std::cout << "genSuperTex(): Texture generation error = " << gerror << std::endl; // no error here

  // Setting texture parameters:
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gerror = glGetError();
  if (gerror) std::cout << "genSuperTex(): Texture param error = " << gerror << std::endl; // no error here
    
  // Generating the storage for the texture:
  // SUPERTEX_DIM = 128 for testing purposes
  glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 1, GL_R8UI, SUPERTEX_DIM, SUPERTEX_DIM, inputSize);
  gerror = glGetError();
  if (gerror) std::cout << "genSuperTex(): glTexStorage3D = " << gerror << std::endl; // no error here
}
```

---

```
void fillSuperTex() {
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0); // Just out of paranoia
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, superBufferID); // It is still bound, but out of paranoia.
  unsigned int index = 0;

  // I have tree of data, which all want to insert their data into the super texture
  root->insertToGLSuperBuffer(superBufferID, superBufferSize, index);
}

void TSDFMesh_SVT::insertToGLSuperBuffer(const GLuint aTexID, const unsigned int size, unsigned int & index) {
  GLuint error;

  error = glGetError();
  if (error) std::cout << "TSDFMesh_SVT::insertToGLSuperBuffer(): prev Error = " << error << std::endl; // no error here, to ensure the error is not from a previous operation

  // How many z-slices are needed for the data:
  GLsizei local_size = meSegmentCount(svtMap->getSize(), SUPERTEX_SEG_SIZE); // = 2, during debugging

  glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, index, SUPERTEX_DIM, SUPERTEX_DIM, local_size, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, svtMap->getData()->DataPointer());
  // SUPERTEX_DIM = 128
  
  error = glGetError(); // <------------------------- Here I get: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
  if (error) std::cout << "TSDFMesh_SVT::insertToGLSuperBuffer(): gl Error = " << error << std::endl;
}
```

I also tried using glTextureSubImage() instead of glTexSubImage() with aTexID as first parameter instead, but to no use.

From the listed errors on the opengl reference:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated by glTextureSubImage3D if texture is not the name of an existing texture object.

Cannot be the case as I use glTexSubImage3D and not glTextureSubImage3D. Also I bind the texture at the beginning of fillSuperTex() and during the traversal of the tree no glBindTexture() operation is done.

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the texture array has not been defined by a previous glTexImage3D or glTexStorage3D operation.

This seems to be the most likely error in my opinion. But in my opinion I have done everything correct with creating the buffer. At least I don't get any errors when it is called. And I used a breakpoint to check that the function genSuperTex() is actually called.

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if type is one of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE_3_3_2, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE_2_3_3_REV, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5_REV and format is not GL_RGB.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if type is one of GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4_REV, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_1_5_5_5_REV, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2, or GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV and format is neither GL_RGBA nor GL_BGRA.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if format is GL_STENCIL_INDEX and the base internal format is not GL_STENCIL_INDEX.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to the GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER target and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to the GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER target and the data would be unpacked from the buffer object such that the memory reads required would exceed the data store size.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to the GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER target and pixels is not evenly divisible into the number of bytes needed to store in memory a datum indicated by type.

In all these cases, the named conditions do not apply.

If anyone has an idea what the error here is, please let me know.

Comment: "*3D_TEXTURES don't have a limit*" They most assuredly do: `GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE`.

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct. I checked the limit a few weeks ago, it is 16384^3 on my graphics card. I forgot about it, because it was more than large enough. (Actually the texture size exceeds the available VRAM, if you would use 1 Byte per voxel.)

Comment: Given the amount of data you're working with, it would probably be better to just use an SSBO rather than a texture. Especially since you clearly don't need filtering.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem:
I tried somewhere else to just testwise create a texture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &testtex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, testtex);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R8UI, 64, 64, 64, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

and I found out that whenever internalformat is R8UI, I get the error. For GL_R8 or GL_RED everything works, but if I change to an integer format (R8I or R8UI) I get the error, although these interal formats are listed as valid entries.

( https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage3D.xhtml )

Is this a problem with my graphics card (NVIDIA) or does anybody else get that error?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; it just points at where the problem (or at least, ***a*** problem) is.